# What's the screen size of an app when running on iPad Air?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am testing an app developed for iPhone on an iPad.

What is the screen size of the App when running on iPad Air? I see a x1 symbol suggesting that runs in native iPhone size but I am not sure.

Comment: Screen size measured in what?  Inches, pixels, points, or something else?

Comment: I assume points, as per Apple standard.

Answer (score 1):

iPad air uses @2x retina images for the assets. The screen resolution is 2048-by-1536 but the real estate (use actually lay out UI elements using the real estate not the actual resolution) is 1024 by 768.

Comment: what about the iphone apps running there? What's the resolution of these?

Comment: The iphone apps run on 3.5" mode (like the screens of iphone 4/4s)